# TTY goes blank after a couple seconds on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, boot, grub2, nvidia, boot-repair

I recently got an NVIDIA GPU and installed Ubuntu 14.04 on my hard drive. My problem is that Ubuntu is no longer booting up. When I boot to that hard drive, I get a blank screen. When I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> (or go to any of the other TTYs) I get the usual login request for a second or two before the screen goes blank again. I can log in by typing half my username, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> again, type other half and hit enter, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> again and entering my password.

Before this, Ubuntu had gotten stuck in a loop at the login screen, so I started trying various fixes I saw on askUbuntu, such as boot-repair, reinstalling lightdm and Xauthority, messing with grub2, but something must have made it worse because now I can't even attempt a fix with TTY without the screen going blank every two seconds.

Any idea what I should do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well jss367, you ended up wiping all of Linux on your HD and putting on a fresh copy. This obviously worked, but I thought of something else you should have tried first. All the issues were probably related to the NVIDIA drivers so you should have tried `sudo apt-get remove --purge nvidia-*` first. You'll get 'em next time!

Comment: Thanks! I was booting to a black screen post-grub, and my TTY would go black every few seconds. Super frustrating, but your command worked immediately.